# What does 「ここでこなんことをしてられない！」mean?

Tags: translation

The sentence 「ここでこなんことをしてられない！」comes from a book I'm reading. I have no idea where してられない comes from. My guess is that it's some colloquial potential form of する or something (there's a song named じっとしてられない), but I might be completely wrong. Can someone please help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, 「こなん」 should be 「こんな」 unless it is in a dialect I am unfamiliar with.

> 「ここでこんなことをしてられない！」

「してられない」 is the informal form of 「して**い**られない」= "***(I) can't be doing***".  So, it is the ***negative, potential and progressive*** form of 「する」.

In informal speech, the 「い」 is often dropped from phrases such as 「～て**い**る」、「～て**い**た」, etc.  Unless you are very new to the language, you must have encountered this phenomenon before.

The sentence, therefore, means:

> "I can't be doing something like this here!"